# Try to add module of DataDroid'. but it gives an Error Minimum required is 19.1.0

Tags: java, android

I have installed all last versions of tools
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TIHYv.jpg)

And in gradle also is the last version

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.android.newsapp"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

But the error is

```
Error:The SDK Build Tools revision (19.0.0) is too low for project ':DataDroid'. Minimum required is 19.1.0
```

Comment: I don't think you are showing `DataDroid/build.gradle`

Comment: @cricket_007 yes that was the problem. I have made instal tools in the wrond gradle file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that i was changing version in app gradle not in module gradle file. After updating version in module gradle everything start work